# Converting altitude to z-level (and vice versa)

Tags: google-maps, openlayers-3, cesiumjs

When using ol3-cesium and the map is in 3d mode, calling map.getView().getZoom() returns undefined. This might affect setZoom as well.

I understand we are in a 3d world, so there are no z-levels as in the tiled maps. On the other hand, Google Maps calculates a z-equivalent when coming back grom 3d to 2d.

How can I convert from height to a z-equivalent? Any formula, taking into account the latitude and altitude, to get the z equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy formula to get a 2D "Z" value from 3D, because the 3D camera can be tilted, can see different levels of tiles in the foreground vs the background, etc.

For individual tiles however, there are specific known "Level" values from the imagery quadtree.  You can see these in [Cesium Inspector](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/CesiumViewer/index.html?inspector=1) by clicking the little `+` next to the word `Terrain` on the right side, and then put a checkmark on `Show tile coordinates`.  The coordinates shown include `L`, `X`, and `Y`, where `L` is the tile's level (0 being the most zoomed-out, higher numbers more zoomed in), and `X` and `Y` are 2D positions within the imagery layer.

I posted an [answer on GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129903/cesium-3d-determining-the-map-scale-of-the-viewed-globe/144496#144496) that shows how to reach in and grab these tiles, the same way Cesium Inspector does, along with a number of caveats involved.  You could potentially look for the highest-level visible tile, and use that as your "Z" value.

Comment: Your comment is very relevant to finding out the Z-level of the images to be retrieved. On the other hand, for my need I can completely ignore the tilting, since there is no such thing in the 2D map (any tilting gets replaced with looking straight down).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not accurate, but sharing in case this is of use to anyone.

I have moved to several altitudes in Google Maps, switching between the 2D and 3D maps, writing down the z or altitude shown in the address bar:

```
 z      altitude (metres)
-----   -----------------
 3          10311040
 4           5932713
 5           2966357
 6           1483178
 7            741589
 8.6          243624
11.35          36310
13.85           6410
15.26           2411
17.01            717
18.27            214
19.6             119
20.77             50
21                44
```

With the above correspondences, I have [approximated the following function](http://www.mycurvefit.com/):

```
function altitudeToZoom(altitude) {
    var A = 40487.57;
    var B = 0.00007096758;
    var C = 91610.74;
    var D = -40467.74;

    return D+(A-D)/(1+Math.pow(altitude/C, B));
}
```

Comment: It's good enough for my context. But I suggest to replace `var` by `const` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your formula, the reverse conversion should be:

altitude = C * Math.pow((A-D)/(zoomLevel-D) -1, 1/B);

Comment: Thanks, someone might find it useful. Though, my formula is not too accurate to begin with.

Comment: And I thank you for providing the original calculations. I'm integrating Cesium with Mapstraction,and the formulas seem to work just fine. BTW, should be Math.round(D+(A-D)/(1+Math.pow(altitude/C, B))). I'm facing some challenges on converting the cesium camera view(extent,scale) to map extent rectangle(map bounds), any idea on that (2D/3D) ?

Comment: Well, it'd be Math.round() if you were only interested in integer zoom levels. But if you care about the difference between zoom 7 and zoom 7.5, you should not use the round.

Comment: I meant the reversed formula is: zoomLevel = Math.round(D+(A-D)/(1+Math.pow(altitude/C, B))); Google maps, ESRI, openLayers only accept integer zoom levels

Comment: Note that OpenLayers does accept non-integer zoom levels.